# How to fix SQL for AWS Athena

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I'm moving SQL from Redshift to AWS Athena, but I'm having trouble because the SQL is giving me errors.

```
SELECT abc_name AS bca_name,
CASE
  WHEN name = 'aaa' THEN 'AAC'
  WHEN name = 'bbb' THEN 'BBA'
  WHEN name = 'ccc' THEN 'CCB'
END AS abc
FROM master_table
WHERE abc IS NOT NULL;
```

This SQL gave me an error: it says that there is no abc column because abc in the where clause is read earlier than in the select clause.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Pro tip: if you have an error, put it in a quote block (using `>` in Markdown) and put some of it in your title ("how to fix SQL" is rather vague). This will be helpful to people in the future who have the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common SQL problem.  You can't refer to an alias defined in the `SELECT` clause in the `WHERE` clause of the same query.  But you don't even need to use the alias to get your desired logic, just use a `WHERE IN (...)`:

```sql
SELECT abc_name AS bca_name,
       CASE name WHEN 'aaa' THEN 'AAC'
                 WHEN 'bbb' THEN 'BBA'
                 WHEN 'ccc' THEN 'CCB' END AS abc
FROM master_table
WHERE name IN ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc');
```

If you really did need to refer to the alias, you would have to either use a subquery or just repeat the `CASE` expression.  For the former option:

```sql
SELECT bca_name, abc
FROM
(
    SELECT abc_name AS bca_name,
           CASE name WHEN 'aaa' THEN 'AAC'
                     WHEN 'bbb' THEN 'BBA'
                     WHEN 'ccc' THEN 'CCB' END AS abc
    FROM master_table
) t
WHERE abc IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge with me!
I have verified it with AWS Athena. IT WORKS!!!! THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: @SJW Consider accepting the answer by clicking the green checkmark. It not only awards the person who answered your question but also tells other users the problem has been solved. btw., you're not getting a better answer than this one ;)

Comment: @JimJones Gordon Linoff is still asleep (it's the middle of the night in Manhattan).  When he wakes up, your comment might be proven wrong `:-P`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm Sorry to late. it works! so I checked the green check mark. thank you so much and happy today!